# Adding multiple components in Blazor (.razor) component

Tags: blazor, razor-pages

How to achieve this below in Razor?
Render one(1) fragment (Panel) is easy, but how to define these i code?

I could create a class that renders a Panel, but it cant have the Parameter attribute.
The different panels, for eg. Layout.GridView has it's own features.

```
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Panel { get; set; }
```

```
    <GroupPanel PanelType="PanelType.Display">
        <Panel Layout="Layout.GridView"></Panel>
        <Panel Layout="Layout.ListView"></Panel>
        <Panel Layout="Layout.DisplayView"></Panel>
    </GroupPanel>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough information to answer the question with any certainty, other than to make some wild guesses.  What is `<GroupPanel>`?  Is the code you've quotes in the same component?  If @Mayur Ekbote's answer answers your question then ignore this, otherwise please update the question with some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

RenderFragment is essentially a placeholder for a blazor component. It can show multiple components.

GroupPanel.razor

```
  <PanelContainer PanelType="PanelType.Display">
      @Panels
   </PanelContainer >

@code{
   [Parameter]
   public RenderFragment Panels {get;set;}
   // other parameters like PanelType
}
```

Index.razor

```
<GroupPanel PanelType="PanelType.Display">
     <Panels>
        <Panel Layout="Layout.GridView"></Panel>
        <Panel Layout="Layout.ListView"></Panel>
        <Panel Layout="Layout.DisplayView"></Panel>
     <Panels>
</GroupPanel>
```